# Java Latin1 encoded text file

Tags: java, utf-8, latin1

I am trying to create an ISO-8859-15 encoded text file from a java method:

```
public void createLatin1EncodedTextFile(File latin1File, Integer numberOfLines) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
  FileNotFoundException {

  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(latin1File), "8859_1"));
  try {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
      bw.write(new String(generateRandomString().getBytes(), "ISO-8859-15"));
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
    try {
      if (!bw.equals(null)) {
        bw.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The method generateRandomString() generates a random sequence of characters.
The method works fine but when I open it with notepad++ it says that the file is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: For `.getBytes()` you need to specify which charset should be used. see [getBytes(String charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String))

Comment: Do you actually have non-ASCII 7-bit characters in your document? If it's only ASCII, then Notepad++ will report "UTF-8 w/o BOM"

Answer (score 3):

You're doing far more work than you need to do.  The encoding of the file is whatever encoding you pass to the OutputStreamWriter:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(latin1File), "ISO-8859-15"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        bw.write(generateRandomString());
    }
}
```

The whole point of a Writer is that it accepts characters (or Strings) and takes care of the task of encoding them.

The fact that your parameter is named `latin1File` has me wondering whether you really want to create an ISO-8859-15 file, though.

Comment: Still, why does it specify the file created is encoded in UTF-8 when I open it with notepad++.

Comment: If the text is restricted it might be that NotePad++ takes the file for UTF-8 which is a superset of ASCII, as is ISO-8859-1 and ~-15.

If you picked ~15 as it contains the Euro symbol that ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) does not, you might reconsider using Windows Latin-1 ("Windows-1252"). It has also special chars like comma-like quotes.